# Change color second button with java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have two Red buttons. If you click a button the color should change to Green. If you click again it should return to Red. 
Now I succeed to change the color of the first button, but not of the seccond button.
Has someone an idea?

I have already a java script that change the color of one button

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const curColour = button.style.backgroundColor;

  if (curColour === 'red') {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background: red
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="bGeneral" class="button1" name="bGeneral"><b>General</b></button>
<!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p>
<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id="buttonP" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
```

Expect to be able to change color of both buttons

Comment: `.querySelector()` always returns the first matched element. Use `.querySelectorAll()` -> [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andreas already said in the comments. You need `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. That will give you a collection which you must loop through

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (const button of buttons) {
    // ...
}
```

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const curColour = button.style.backgroundColor;

    if (curColour === 'red') {
      button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
      button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background: red
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="bGeneral" class="button1" name="bGeneral"><b>General</b></button>
<!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p>
<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id="buttonP" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toggleClass`. Also use `querySelectorAll` this will give all the buttons. Then iterate this collection and add event listener to it. .Inside callback function use `classList.toggle` to add or remove the class

```js
var button = [...document.querySelectorAll("button")].forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('toggleButtonColor')
  });

})
```

```css
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background: red
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.toggleButtonColor {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">

  <button id="bGeneral" class="button1" name="bGeneral"><b>General</b></button>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>
  <!-- The Next Button Plates -->
  <button id="buttonP" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
</body>
```

Comment: Good answer :) It's little odd tho use `spread operator` along with `var`. Either it's ES6, either it's not.

Comment: In every modern browser (all but IE...) a `NodeList` has a `.forEach()` method so the conversion into an actual array is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different way to deal with the click. Use either `onclick` or `addEventListener`. Here is an example.

I haven't improved the inside of your function tho. Look at @brk answer for opti

```js
function showOrHide(id, name) {
  const button = document.getElementById(id);

  const curColour = button.style.backgroundColor;
  
  if (curColour === 'red' || !curColour) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  background-color: #E3CEF6
}
```

```html
<button id="bGeneral" onclick="showOrHide(this.id, 'General')" class="button1" name="bGeneral">
<b>General</b></button>
<!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p>

<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id="buttonP" onclick="showOrHide(this.id, 'Plates')" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use id :

```
function showOrHide(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  const curColour = element.style.backgroundColor;
  if (curColour === 'red') {

        element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<button  id="bGeneral" onclick="showOrHide(this.id)" class="button1"  name= "bGeneral" ><b>General</b></button> 
  <!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p> 
<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id = "buttonP" onclick="showOrHide(this.id)" class="button1" name= "buttonP" ><b>Plates</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the proper way with your thoughts**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <style>
    button {
      height:40px;
      width:160px;
      border: 4px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
      border-color:red;
      color: yellow;
      padding: 12px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button1 { background: red }

    .button1:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
     <body onload="beginfase()" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;" >

    <button  id="bGeneral" onclick="" class="button1"  name= "bGeneral" ><b>General</b></button> 
      <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br></p> 
    <!-- The Next Button Plates -->
    <button id = "buttonP" onclick="" class="button1" name= "buttonP" ><b>Plates</b></button> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //we are creating an array
    var button = [];
    button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    //we are binding the function to all the elements of the array
    for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        button[i].onclick = function(){
    // this represent the elemement which is being clicked
          if(this.style.backgroundColor === "red"){
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green"
          }
          else{
          this.style.backgroundColor = "red"
          }

        }
    }

    </script>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `onclick` method, and use `querySelectorAll` to select all the buttons

**HTML**

```
<button  id="bGeneral" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="button1"  name= "bGeneral" ><b>General</b></button> 
      <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br></p> 
    <!-- The Next Button Plates -->
    <button id = "buttonP" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="button1" name= "buttonP" ><b>Plates</b></button>
```

**JS**

```
function changeColor (value) {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button1");
    let color = value.style.backgroundColor;
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if (color === 'red') {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green'
      } else {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
      }
    }
  }
```